# how to store form data into sessions on page refresh?

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a form and a add button that adds the same form fields below the existing form. I want to save the data if entered in the above form.
Below is my code

```
<form action="?file=<?= $file ?>" method="post" name="frm_news" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="well">

    <h4>
        Send Daily Work Report
    </h4>

        <table id="prjct_tbl">

            <tr align="left" valign="middle"> 

                <td height="18" class="text7" ><a id="link" href="?file=daily_report.php&prj_num=<?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['prj_num'])){echo 2;}else {$count  =    $_REQUEST['prj_num']; echo $count+1;}?>" >Add another Project</a></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><hr /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" valign="top" > 
                <td colspan="3" align="center"><? if ($MSG != "") {
    echo $MSG;
} ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td width="32%" align="right">Project Name :&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="68%"><select name="pid[]" id="pid">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                        <? for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) { ?>
                            <option value="<?= $data[$i]['id'] ?>"><?= $data[$i]['pname'] ?></option>
                    <? } ?>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 

                <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color:red">*</span> Deliverable :&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="d_id[]">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT tbl_deliverable.*, user_to_deliverable.d_id from tbl_deliverable, user_to_deliverable where tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id AND user_to_deliverable.u_id = '".$info['id']."'";
                            $res = mysql_query($sql);
                            while ($d_data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                                ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $d_data['id']?>"><?php echo $d_data['name']?></option>
                                    <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                  
                <td align="right"  valign="top"><span style="color:red">*</span>Time Spent :&nbsp;</td>
                <td><select name="hrs[]" class="Field" id="hrs" required style="width: 80px;">
                        <option value="" selected>Hour</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>

                    </select>
                    <select name="min[]" class="Field" id="min" required style="width: 80px;">
                        <option value="">Minute</option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="32">32</option>
                        <option value="33">33</option>
                        <option value="34">34</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="36">36</option>
                        <option value="37">37</option>
                        <option value="38">38</option>
                        <option value="39">39</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="41">41</option>
                        <option value="42">42</option>
                        <option value="43">43</option>
                        <option value="44">44</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="46">46</option>
                        <option value="47">47</option>
                        <option value="48">48</option>
                        <option value="49">49</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="51">51</option>
                        <option value="52">52</option>
                        <option value="53">53</option>
                        <option value="54">54</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                        <option value="56">56</option>
                        <option value="57">57</option>
                        <option value="58">58</option>
                        <option value="59">59</option>                  
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                  
                <td align="right"  valign="top">Percentage of deliverable completed :&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="percent[]" id="percent" type="text">   
                    <input name="employee" type="hidden" id="employee" value="<?= $info['fname'] ?> <?= $info['lname'] ?>">
                    <input name="email" type="hidden" id="email" value="<?= $info['email'] ?>">
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?= $info['id'] ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td align="right" valign="top"  nowrap>Comments:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><textarea name="comments[]" id="comments"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            if(isset($_REQUEST['prj_num'])) {
                for($l=1;$l<$_REQUEST['prj_num'];$l++){
                ?>
            <tr >
                <td width="32%" align="right">Project Name :&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="68%"><select name="pid[]" id="pid">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                        <? for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) { ?>
                            <option value="<?= $data[$i]['id'] ?>"><?= $data[$i]['pname'] ?></option>
                    <? } ?>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 

                <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color:red">*</span> Deliverable :&nbsp;</td>

<td>
                    <select name="d_id[]">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT tbl_deliverable.*, user_to_deliverable.d_id from tbl_deliverable, user_to_deliverable where tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.d_id AND user_to_deliverable.u_id = '".$info['id']."'";
                            $res = mysql_query($sql);
                            while ($d_data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                                ?>
                        <option value ="<?php echo $d_data['id']?>"><?php echo $d_data['name']?></option>
                                    <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                  
                <td align="right"  valign="top"><span style="color:red">*</span>Time Spent :&nbsp;</td>
                <td><select name="hrs[]" class="Field" id="hrs" required style="width: 80px;">
                        <option value="" selected>Hour</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>

                    </select>
                    <select name="min[]" class="Field" id="min" required style="width: 80px;">
                        <option value="">Minute</option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="32">32</option>
                        <option value="33">33</option>
                        <option value="34">34</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="36">36</option>
                        <option value="37">37</option>
                        <option value="38">38</option>
                        <option value="39">39</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="41">41</option>
                        <option value="42">42</option>
                        <option value="43">43</option>
                        <option value="44">44</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="46">46</option>
                        <option value="47">47</option>
                        <option value="48">48</option>
                        <option value="49">49</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="51">51</option>
                        <option value="52">52</option>
                        <option value="53">53</option>
                        <option value="54">54</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                        <option value="56">56</option>
                        <option value="57">57</option>
                        <option value="58">58</option>
                        <option value="59">59</option>                  
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                  
                <td align="right"  valign="top">Percentage of deliverable completed :&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="percent[]" id="percent" type="text">   
                    <input name="employee" type="hidden" id="employee" value="<?= $info['fname'] ?> <?= $info['lname'] ?>">
                    <input name="email" type="hidden" id="email" value="<?= $info['email'] ?>">
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?= $info['id'] ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td align="right" valign="top"  nowrap>Comments:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><textarea name="comments[]" id="comments"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            }}
            ?>
            <tr bordercolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <td align="center"> 
                </td>
                <td align="left">&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="  Send  " class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value=" Reset " class="btn"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>



</form>
```

this is adding the form elements but on page refresh, the form fields are empty empty

Comment: Something like: `<input name="somefield" id="somefield"<?php if(!empty($_POST['somefield'])) echo " value=\"" . someSanitiseFunction($_POST['somefield']) . "\""; ?>" />` ... basically post the form to itself and retrieve the data from $_POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can see that the fields would be empty is if the $info array is empty or undefined. Are you sure you are repopulating that array when the page is refreshed (after form submit)? Can you switch on error reporting? Possibly you'll see some error messages inside the fields.

Comment: i am not submitting the form, i am redirecting to the same page through the link

Comment: If you are not submitting the form, then the user data never arrives to the server. So you can't use sessions. You could use javascript write a cookie to the client which contains the values input in the fields so far, and populate the fields by reading that cookie on the page onLoad event. Probably the easiest way would be to use javascript to render the new field elements, without reloading the page.